# 404 not found - JS not sending variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send some variables to PHP script and then to upload them in MySQL db.

Here is my JS script:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {endadres:endadres,stadres:stadres,amount_of_carriers:amount_of_carriers, price_finalized:price_finalized },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
  })
```

All of variables are extisting inside the same function (I checked it via "alert()").

Here is my PHP code:

```
    // Check connection
    if($link === false)
    {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['FirstName']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['LastName']);
$start_adress = $_POST['startadress'];
$end_adress = $_POST['endadress'];
$Price = $_POST['finallprice'];
$CarriersQuant = $_POST['carriersamo'];


// Attempt insert query execution
$post = "INSERT INTO Orders (FirstName, LastName, StartAdress, EndAdress, Price, CarriersQuant) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$start_adress', '$end_adress', '$Price', '$CarriersQuant')";
```

LastName and FirstName are taken from .html, and I can upload them into my DB, but I am not able to get variables from js.

Error from console:
[image: Error 404]

Comment: A 404 error means that the server does not recognize the URL. Are you sure it shouldn't be `"./insert.php"`?

Comment: Your JS is wrong as a start. Try `data: $('#formIdHere').serializeArray();`

Comment: The slash you have in "url: /insert.php" is telling it to look in the root directory for insert.php. That is probably why you are getting a 404 error.

Comment: I tried to do the direct link, like "www.website.com/ftp/insert.php" but it is not working also.

Comment: @DenissAkmaikin and what happens if you open this url in browser?

Comment: It works, but I am getting empty field in DB, but its fine

Comment: Also, if I will put in .php code like this `$first_name = $_POST['FirstName'];
 $last_name = $_POST['LastName'];` it will not send anything. Have no idea why

Comment: Tip: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names in the ajax post doesn't correspond with what you try to extract in the receiving end (PHP). If you stick with these names in JavaScript:

```
data: {
  endadres,
  stadres,
  amount_of_carriers,
  price_finalized
},
```

You must use the same key to collect them in PHP:

```
$foo = $_POST["endadres"]
```

To debug, I often find it useful to add this debug output to see all posted variables:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

On a second note (unrelated to your question though), your SQL insert statement is **very dangerous**. You are concatenating the variables directly from the external request into the database query string, which means that a potential offender could post something like:

```
carriersamo: "'; DROP TABLE Orders;"
```

which would drop your `Orders` table from your database. I recommend you read up on PHP's PDO module, where it's quite easy to prepare "safe" statements to the database. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: While PDO is a great idea, the original question is `mysqli` and that has a prepared statement system as well that works just fine.